# Drag an Image in XNA

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, xna-4.0

I am working on an app in which images are flying on the Screen.
I need to implement:

1. Hold onto any of the flying images on Tap
2. Drag the image to certain position of the user's choice by letting the user hold it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another easy way to do dragging.
Just draw your image (Texture2d) with respect to a Rectangle instead of Vector2.
Your image variables should look like this

```
Texture2d image;
Rectangle imageRect;
```

Draw your image with respect to "imageRect" in Draw() method.

```
spriteBatch.Draw(image,imageRect,Color.White);
```

Now in Update() method handle your image with single touch input.

```
//Move your image with your logic

TouchCollection touchLocations = TouchPanel.GetState();
foreach(TouchLocation touchLocation in touchLocations)
{
  Rectangle touchRect = new Rectangle 
    (touchLocation.Position.X,touchLocation.Position.Y,10,10);
  if(touchLocation.State == TouchLocationState.Moved
     && imageRect.Intersects(touchRect))
  {
   imageRect.X = touchRect.X;
   imageRect.Y = touchRect.Y;
  }
//you can bring more beauty by bringing centre point 
//of imageRect instead of initial point by adding width
//and height to X and Y respectively and divide it by 2
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a drag-and-drag example in XNA here: http://geekswithblogs.net/mikebmcl/archive/2011/03/27/drag-and-drop-in-a-windows-xna-game.aspx

Answer (score 1):

When you load your image in, you'll need a BoundingBox or Rectangle Object to control where it is.

So, in the XNA app on your phone, you should have a couple of objects declared for your texture.

```
Texture2D texture;
BoundingBox bBox;
Vector2 position;
bool selected;
```

Then after you load your image content, keep your bounding box updated with the position of your image.

```
bBox.Min = new Vector3(position, 1.0f);
bBox.Max = new Vector3(position.X + texture.Width, position.Y + texture.Height, 0f);
```

Then also in your update method, you should have a touch collection initialized to handle input from the screen, get the positions of the touch collection, loop through them and see if they intersect your boundingbox.

```
foreach (Vector2 pos in touchPositions)
{
   BoundingBox bb = new BoundingBox();
   bb.Min = new Vector3(pos, 1.0f);
   bb.Max = new Vector3(pos, 0f);

   if (bb.Intersects(bBox)
   {
       if (selected)
       {
           //do something
       }
       else
       {
           selected = true;
       }
   }
}
```

From there, you have whether your object is selected or not. Then just use the gestures events to determine what you want to do with your texture object.